# Docker и git clone: как бороться с using cache?

Tags: c#, docker, github, .net-core, контейнеры

Уважаемые господа,

я делаю вот что:

у меня есть исходный код (мой) моего простенького приложения, написанного на C# / NET Core 6.0, лежащий в репозитории на гитхабе.

Я пишу Dockerfile, который должен взять этот код, и собрать приложение.

Это - довольно распространненная практика, как я понял - отдельный контейнер, который собирает приложение.

вот этот докерфайл, в нём нет ничего особенно оригинального (ия его нарочно не *оптимизировал*):

```
    FROM ubuntu:latest
    RUN apt-get update
    RUN apt-get install -y wget
    RUN wget https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/22.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb -O packages-microsoft-prod.deb
    RUN dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb
    RUN rm packages-microsoft-prod.deb
    RUN apt-get update
    RUN apt-get install -y apt-transport-https
    ENV DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT=1
    RUN apt-get install -y dotnet-sdk-6.0
    # dotnet sdk is installed!

    RUN apt-get install -y git
    ARG ssh_prv_key
    ARG ssh_pub_key

    # Authorize SSH Host
    RUN mkdir -p /root/.ssh
    RUN chmod 0700 /root/.ssh
    RUN ssh-keyscan github.com > /root/.ssh/known_hosts

    # Add the keys and set permissions
    RUN echo "$ssh_prv_key" > /root/.ssh/id_rsa
    RUN echo "$ssh_pub_key" > /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
    RUN chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa
    RUN chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

    WORKDIR /App
    RUN git clone git@github.com:junecat/InternalProject.git
    WORKDIR /App/InternalProject
    RUN dotnet publish -c release
    CMD mkdir /App/publish-output/
    WORKDIR /App/publish-output
    CMD cp -r /App/InternalProject/bin/Release/net6.0/* /App/publish-output
```

Из этого докерфайла я строю образ контейнера, котрый должен собрать придожение, командой

```
    docker build -t internal_project_build-image --build-arg ssh_prv_key="$(cat ~/.ssh/ro1_key)" --build-arg ssh_pub_key="$(cat ~/.ssh/ro1_key.pub)" -f Dockerfile .
```

Как видите, на этом этапе мои `readonly`-ключи для доступа к `github` попадают с хоста в контейнер.

Затем я запускаю контейнер командой

```
    docker run -it --name internal_project_build-cont  -v /home/konst/BuildingContainer/publish-output:/App/publish-output -d internal_project_build-image
```

И у меня мой Dockerfile уже работал так, что я просто чувствовал себя властелином мира. Всё было классно.

До того момнета, как я внёс *небольшие* изменения в исходный код, а потом поопробовал пересобрать приложение.

**Приложение собралось из старого исходного кода.** я это видел по ошибкам, которые оно выдаёт. Именно на исправление этих ошибок были направлены мои "небольшим изменения".

И тогда я заметил, что при сборке образа контейнера в ответ на команду

```
    RUN git clone git@github.com:junecat/InternalProject.git
```

я вижу в консоли команды `docker build` сообщение

```
    Step 22/24 : RUN git clone git@github.com:junecat/InternalProject.git
     ---> Using cache
     ---> 3c5778dd3426
```

*"Э! — сказали мы с Петром Ивановичем"*

Похоже, по какой то неизвестной мне причине умный докер вместо того, чтобы сходить на гитхаб на свежими исходниками рещил, что "и так сойдёт!"

**Как бы мне его от этого отучить?**

Кстати, поверхностым поиском я [вижу](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36996046/how-to-prevent-dockerfile-caching-git-clone), что я не один мучаюсь. Но что то ни один из приведенны в том вопросе - ответе способов не кажется мне подходящим...

Также, спасибо Вам, если Вы дадите мне советы по оптимизации того процесса, которым я занимаюсь (построение приложения в контейнере)

Заранее большое спасибо за советы!

**Небольшое дополнение**

Во первых, спасибо большое tym32167 за совет использовать git pull после git clone. Это помогло, но, как и предсказывали в комментариях, ровно на один раз. Потом, видимо, "все закешировалось" опять. Конечно, я попробую еще раз проверить, может, я невнимательный был, но, кажется, это все таки не решает проблему.

Пока для меня проблему "решило" использование команды `docker builder prune`. Но я не зря взял слово "решило" в кавычки: эта команда сбрасывает весь кеш билдера. То есть, в следующий раз он ВСЁ, вот **ВСЁ** будет качать заново. По эффекту это похоже на то, что есть Вам не понравилась конкретная божья коровка на былинке - нужно выжечь весь луг напалмом и вырастить его заново.

Comment: я не в теме, просто подумал, что если после клонирования добавить команду git pull ?

Comment: @tym32167 - спасибо за идею, сейчас попробую!

Comment: @tym32167 и результат его вызова тоже поместится в кэш и в будущем будет браться из того же кэша, наверное?

Comment: @andreymal странно было бы кешировать pull?

Comment: вот тут еще что то по теме есть https://stackoverflow.com/q/36996046/312041

Comment: @tym32167 докер ничего об этом не знает, он просто выполняет RUN'ы и кэширует их результат

Comment: @andreymal ну ок ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Вообще обычно код приложения добавляют через какие-нибудь ADD или COPY, которые вроде как работают с кэшем более умно. Использовать для этого git clone как-то странно

Comment: @andreymal - я согласен, и много раз видел такую практику припостроении контейнеров для node.js. Но я не могу придумать, как "автоматизировать" забирание кода из репы, кроме как использовать git clone внутри контейнера

Comment: а в чем проблема с "автоматизацией", вы создаете dockerfile, который использует add/copy и комитите его в туже репу, а на билд сервере или ещё где-то делаете git clone и docker build

Comment: Dockerfile перед сборкой откуда берется? Не из репозитория разве? Это я к тому, что `git clone` все равно придется делать до запуска docker для того чтоб Dockerfile достать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Благодаря комметариям к моему вопросу, я понял, что я "*копал глубоко, но не в том месте*"

Нет смысла для моего "простого, как рельсы" проекта связываться с тем, чтобы внутри контейнера забирать исходники из репозитория и что то из них собирать.

То есть, это, конечно, круто - когда контейнер всё это может делать, и мы для этого в него передаём снаружи ключи и т.п. - но, видимо, эту технику надо использовать для более сложных целей, например, в случае, когда какая то часть проекта обязана собираться из исходников...

Если же у нас есть "просто проект" - то лучшим способом его сборки будет такой:

1. делаем docker clone
2. в результате мы получаем каталог с исходником проекта. Из него запускаем сборку контейнера и потом запуск контейнера.

Дальше - только одно "косметическое" исправление: на верхнем уровне в этом каталоге лежат всего 2 вещи: Dockerfile и еще один каталог, в котором уже лежит проект в исходниках.

Какую проблему это решает?

Если у нас вдруг появится еще один проект, то это приведет просто к тому, что рядом с докерфайлом будет 2 каталога.

А это может произойти, либо потому, что мы решили, что просто в один репозиторий попадает несколько проектов (очень распространенная практика для небольщих проектов), либо потому, что рядом спроектом как то обычно сами собой появляются тесты, сетап и т.п. сопутствующие проекты.

В общем, я - как примерный мальчик - даже сделал [демо-проект](https://github.com/junecat/BuildDemo), который поясняет мою мысль.

Прект называется BuildDemo, соответственно, после

```
    git clone git@github.com:junecat/BuildDemo.git
```

у Вас появится папочка `~/BuildDemo` (буду считать, что всё происходит в домашней директории. Если нет - подправьте пути в тех местах, где это важно)

затем мы заходим в эту папку, и делаем

```
    docker build -t build_demo-image -f Dockerfile .

    docker run -it --name build_demo-cont  -v ~/BuildDemo/publish-output:/App/publish-output -d build_demo-image
```

Теоретически, можно "воткнуть" в докерфайл последней строчкой `STOPSIGNAL SIGQUIT` и тогда можно будет уже после завершения работы контейнера попасть в него командой

```
    docker exec -it build_demo-cont /bin/bash
```

и посмотреть, как там и что.

А еще - там в проекте лежит второй докерфайл (я, не мудрствуя лукаво, назвал его `Dockerfile2`).

Он собирает из результатов работы первого контейнера - второй контейнер, уже "рабочий":

```
    docker build -t csharp_run_demo-image -f Dockerfile2 .
```

и запускает его командой

```
    docker run -it --name csharp_run_demo-cont  -v ~/BuildDemo/Logs/:/App/Logs/  -d csharp_run_demo-image
```

(также, эти команды лежат в )

Затем - вы можете в папке Logs, которая будет создана в `~/BuildDemo`, и убедиться, что контейнер отработал и записал своё "hello world" в лог.

Большое спасибо всем, кто помог мне разобраться!